# Media query only working between 1024 and 1280

Tags: css, media-queries

I have this media query:

```
  @media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .discount-box-primary {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

The `.discount-box-primary` element is supposed to not be shown between 360 and 1280, but the `display: none` property only gets activated between 1024 and 1280, bellow that the element is shown again.

I can't find out why the media query doesn't work between 360 and 1024.

---

#### Solution:

The problem was that that media query was inside another larger media query which was overriding the behavior of the new one. This was on a page with nearly 3000 lines and I didn't thought to look for a 'parent'. Thanks for the answers and comments.

I'm not able to delete the question, voted to close but the vote seems to have aged away, if that's possible.

Comment: Maybe it is getting overwritten somewhere else and set to block again. Can't say much without more info.

Comment: Seems to be overwritten as mentioned. The media query works fine on here. Please post a [example].

Comment: Sorry, I'll add an MRE, I was hopping this would be my mistake and fixable as is.

Comment: You need to put this query AFTER anything else, since `@media` queries are part of the cascade. Also, make sure that the specificity for the selector is greater, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to have a base, and define min amounts. This way it's easier to manage your breakpoints. Have a primary rule defined, then work your way up the min-widths instead of using ranges. See how something like this works for you:

```css
.discount-box-primary { display: inline-block; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
   .discount-box-primary { display: none; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
   .discount-box-primary { display: inline-block; }
}
```